# Generate thumbnail images in sveltekit/vite on build

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I've got a sveltekit application where I'd like to have an image preview / thumbnail on one page which then takes you to the full image upon clicking onto the thumbnail.

However, I would like to automate the creation of the thumbnails for me, as I want to...

- ...use a static adapter / static files
- ...not have to manually create / manage all the different thumbnail & original images
- ...keep the repository clean by not having what is essentially duplicates of images just in different folders and sizes.

As for the code, here is a basic example that shows what I want to do:

`routes/[comic]/+page.svelte` (this one should use the thumbnails as a preview for the pages)

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { page } from "$app/stores";
    import { comics } from "irrelevant";

    const comic = comics.find((comic) => comic.id === $page.params.comic);
    const pages = Array.from(Array(comic?.pages ?? 0).keys());
</script>

{#if comic}
    <h1>{comic.name}</h1>
    {#each pages as page}
        <a href="/{comic.id}/{page}">
            <img src="/thumbs/{comic.id}/{page}.jpg" alt="Page {page + 1}" title="Page {page + 1}">
        </a>
    {/each}
{:else}
    <h1>Error</h1>
    <h2>Comic nicht gefunden</h2>
{/if}
```

`routes/[comic]/[page]/+page.svelte` (this one should show the full image in its own page)

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { page } from "$app/stores";
    import { comics } from "irrelevant";

    const comic = comics.find(
        (comic) => comic.id === $page.params.comic
    );
    const currentPage: number = Number($page.params.page);
</script>

{#if comic}
    <h1>{comic.name} - Page {currentPage}</h1>
    <img src="/images/{comic.id}/{currentPage}.jpg" alt="{comic.name} - Page {currentPage+ 1}" />
{:else}
    <h1>Not found</h1>
{/if}
```

---

I have tried to create a `thumbs.js` file that generates the thumbnails for me in the build folder automatically (it just recursively goes through `/static/images/`, generates a thumbnail and saves it to `/build/thumbs/`, which works fine), but that has the problem that vite doesn't recognize those paths when building the project, causing the build to fail with the error message

```
Error: Not found: /thumbs/comic1/0.jpg
    at resolve ([redacted]/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2713:18)
    at resolve ([redacted]/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2588:34)
    at #options.hooks.handle ([redacted]/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2757:59)
    at respond ([redacted]/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2586:43)
```

---

So, to reiterate, my question is:
**How can I generate thumbnails on the fly that are not part of the repository/project structure and that get recognized during buildtime?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a Vite plugin that generates the thumbnails as part of the regular build process.

You can import the images via [glob import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) to make sure they are all included, a `query` can be added to help the plugin identify the import. It should also be possible to import the individual files via [dynamic import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import) but then the import will by asynchronous.

```js
const thumbnailPaths = import.meta.glob(
    '/images/*.jpg', // whatever glob pattern captures all relevant images
    { query: 'thumbnail', eager: true },
);
```

The plugin can covert the images and emit them as assets, something along the lines of:

```js
const thumbnailPlugin = command => ({
    name: 'thumbnail-plugin',
    transform(code, id) {
        const [path, query] = id.split('?');
        if (query != 'thumbnail')
            return;

        // [Transform image here]

        if (command == 'build') {
            const name = basename(path);
            const assetId = this.emitFile({
                type: 'asset',
                fileName: `assets/${name}`, // might be missing a hash
                source: thumbnailData,
            });

            // return path to asset
        }
        else {
            // dev mode, e.g. return a data-URL
        }
    }
});
```

The plugin is added in the `vite.config.js`, the `command` is provided by `defineConfig`:

```js
export default defineConfig(({ command }) => {
    return {
        // ...
        plugins: [
            // ...
            thumbnailPlugin(command),
        ],
    };
});
```